# how to skip a directory while reading using dirent.h

Tags: c++, c, opendir, dirent.h

i am trying to recursively open files using the functionality  provided in **dirent.h**

My problem is:
i could not make it to skip directories which failed to open. I want it to open the directories which it can and skip those which it can't and move to the next directory instead of exiting with failure.
What should i do to fix this?

Here is a simple code i tried to use

```
int acessdirs(const char *path)
{
    struct dirent *entry;
    DIR *dp;
    char fpath[300];
    if(dp=opendir(path))
    {
        while((entry=readdir(dp)))
            do things here
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"error opening directory";
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I used this same style on `windows 7` and it works fine.But it crashed on `windows xp` and when i debugged it i found that it crashes while trying to open `"system volume information"`.
I really dont need to access this folder and i was hoping if there is any way to skip it.

Here is my real code:

It is a little bit long.

```
int listdir(const char *path) 
{
  struct dirent *entry;
  DIR *dp;

  if(dp = opendir(path))
  {
    struct stat buf ;

    while((entry = readdir(dp)))
    {
        std::string p(path);
        p += "\\";
        p += entry->d_name;
         char fpath[300];
        if(!stat(p.c_str(), &buf))
        {
            if(S_ISREG(buf.st_mode))
            {  
                sprintf(fpath,"%s\\%s",path,entry->d_name);
                stat(fpath, &buf);
                std::cout<<"\n Size of \t"<<fpath<<"\t"<<buf.st_size;
                fmd5=MDFile (fpath);        
            }//inner second if
            if(S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode) &&  
         // the following is to ensure we do not dive into directories "." and ".."
                      strcmp(entry->d_name, ".")  && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") )
            {
                listdir(p.c_str());
            }
        }//inner first if
        else
            std::cout << "ERROR in stat\n";
    }//end while
    closedir(dp);
  }//first if
  else
  {
      std::cout << "ERROR in opendir\n";
      return 0;
  }
  return 1;   

 }//listdir()
```

Comment: `access` is spelled with two `c`.

Comment: How does this code even compile? You have a variable called `dip` and you refer to it as `dp`. Also, in the future, please indent your code so that it is comprehensible.

Comment: You pasted too little code for us to even understand where the problem is. Is `accessdirs` called in a loop? What does that loop do when `0` is returned? Where's the recursion exactly? Does the "do things here" call `accessdirs`?

Comment: @Greg: You were probably right, why delete your answer? The function either calls itself recursively or is inside a loop in its caller. Most likely, when it returns `0`, that causes the loop to terminate without continuing to process other entries in that same directory.

Comment: The program crashes probably because you don't check errors properly. The code we need to see is in `do things here`

Comment: @user1366861 how is fpath declared?

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest problem seems to be here:

```
sprintf(fpath,"%s\\%s",path,entry->d_name);
stat(fpath, &buf);
```

Without seeing `fpath`'s declatation, it's tough to tell for certain, but you're either

- Overflowing `fpath` in the `sprintf` call, leading to undefined behavior. "System Volume Information" is a long name. You should really use `snprintf`.
- Not checking the return value of the `stat` call. If it returns `-1`, I'n not sure what the contents of `buf` will be.

More importantly, if you can use POSIX stuff, the function [`ftw`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/ftw.html) is standard, and should provide most of the functionality you're trying to implement here.

Comment: sorry. I was away until now. I have put line of declaration for **fpath**